# Sharing photos on facebook from iOS application without facebook app

Tags: ios, facebook

Is it possible on iOS < 6?

In iOS 6+, I can share using message composer.

What about previous version of iOS? FB SDK share uses facebook app id so it's not the way. 
Maybe i can open native facebook app with scheme like `fb://share/photo/[image_data]?` 
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS < 6, you can always used [ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) plugin.

In this [repository](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit), they share nice example to share image on your fb account.

Have a look at the class `ExampleShareImage`:

```
- (void)loadView 
{
    [super loadView];

    self.imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sanFran.jpg"]] autorelease];

    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height);

    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}

- (void)share
{
    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:imageView.image title:@"San Francisco"];

    /* optional examples
    item.tags = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"bay bridge", @"architecture", @"california", nil];

    //give a source rect in the coords of the view set with setRootViewController:
    item.popOverSourceRect = [self.navigationController.toolbar convertRect:self.navigationController.toolbar.bounds toView:self.view];
     */

    SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];
    [SHK setRootViewController:self];
    [actionSheet showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar];
}
```

You can also integrate [FBConnect](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/) framework provide by Facebook.

Comment: But as fas as I know FBConnect requires facebook app.

Comment: try sharekit but in my 2 apps, I used FBConnect and it never ask me for FB App(One with the SSO in safari and another Login thr dialog box).